# How to install Ubuntu on free DOS OS on Lenovo G580-59-358263 ? (For experienced Lenevo Users)

Tags: 12.04, installation, wireless, 13.04, lenovo

My Lenovo G580-59-358263 laptop will be coming in the next 2-3 days which has pre-installed DOS operating System (No Windows), i prefer that way. Well i've never installed Ubuntu on DOS running laptops before. I want to gain the knowledge before i try hands on installation on this.

Also,

After Installing do you have problems connecting to Network (through wifi or Broadband) ?
What about the drivers ? below is the list of configuration for my Lenovo G580-59-358263 laptop.

laptop info...

OS - Dos,
Ram - 4GB DDR3 -[3MB Cache],
HDD - 500GB,
Graphics - Intel HD 4000

Have you had any problems installing other linux distros ?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't install it on FreeDOS, you'd boot to the LiveCD/LiveUSB and either replace DOS or repartition (the installer should offer you that option) to install alongside DOS. I'd personally opt for replacing DOS.

And for hardware compatibility, try it and see. The basics should be fine but I can't see what sort of wireless chipset it's using from here. You might have to fight it, you might not. There are few wireless issues that can't be resolved though.

Having read a little bit more about the newer Intel HD 4000 chipsets, you might need to poke that a bit to use SNA acceleration but as with the rest of it, this is something you'll find out when you boot it up for the first time. If it's still a problem, it's pretty easy to fix.

Comment: ohk i'll see to it.